# how can we add an element in the map of set...eg .map<int,unordered_multiset<int>>mp; in c++14

Tags: c++11, stl, set, c++14

i want add an element to the mp[x].
map<int,unordered_multiset>adj;

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>brr[i];
    if(brr[i]!=arr[i])
    {
    // i want to add an element 
    //in mp[brr[i]] ;
     
    }
    else
    {
        comp.insert({brr[i],i+1}); //set
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ; also, the compiler error message would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a `map` from `int` to `unordered_multiset<int>`.

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::unordered_multiset<int>> adj;
    
    const int z = 10;
    adj[6].insert(z);
    adj[6].insert({1,2,3});
    
    auto& myset = adj[6];

    for(auto const& x : myset) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
10
```

The examples on cppreference are usually quite good:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#Example
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert#Example

And then you have to find the correct way to insert into the multiset:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/insert

And one of them uses the `initializer_list` `{}`

Comment: adj[99] = {1,2,3}; now i want to add 4 to this set..how could i ..plz provide code

Comment: @shahil198 `adj[99].insert(4)`

Comment: @shahil198 great